# React vs IE11: using variables in jsx makes everything broken

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, jsx

I got some strange error in my app (just in IE11, other browsers work fine). Error is next:

```
Invariant Violation: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%24%24typeof%2C%20type%2C%20key%2C%20ref%2C%20props%2C%20_owner%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
   {
      [functions]: ,
      @@hasInstance: undefined,
      @@isConcatSpreadable: undefined,
      @@iterator: undefined,
      @@match: undefined,
      @@observable: undefined,
      @@react.element: undefined,
      @@replace: undefined,
      @@search: undefined,
      @@species: undefined,
      @@split: undefined,
      @@toPrimitive: undefined,
      @@toStringTag: undefined,
      @@unscopables: undefined,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%24%24typeof%2C%20type%2C%20key%2C%20ref%2C%20props%2C%20_owner%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. ",
      framesToPop: 1,
      message: "Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%24%24typeof%2C%20type%2C%20key%2C%20ref%2C%20props%2C%20_owner%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. ",
      name: "Invariant Violation",
      stack: "Invariant Violation: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%24%24typeof%2C%20type%2C%20key%2C%20ref%2C%20props%2C%20_owner%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
   at Anonymous function (http://10.250.100.213:3000/xxxx/assets/vendors.d853e9b1.chunk.js:1:397243)
   at a (http://10.250.100.213:3000/xxxx/assets/vendors.d853e9b1.chunk.js:1:396940)
   at po (http://10.250.100.213:3000/xxxx/assets/vendors.d853e9b1.chunk.js:1:443987)
   at Anonymous function (http://10.250.100.213:3000/xxxx/assets/vendors.d853e9b1.chunk.js:1:448738)
   at xi (http://10.250.100.213:3000/xxxx/assets/vendors.d853e9b1.chunk.js:1:455626)
   at Pi (http://10.250.100.213:3000/xxxx/assets/vend"
   }
```

I've started with adding polyfills to my app, but it doesn't

Reading documentation and issues don't give me an answer. So I started eliminate components from tree one by one. And finally I found something strange.

so I stacked  at next

```
const text = 'Button';

const buttonClassName = `${className} qa-load-more-button`;
return (
  <Button uiType="load_more">
    <span>{text}</span>
  </Button>
```

doesn’t work , while

```
const text = 'Button';

const buttonClassName = `${className} qa-load-more-button`;
return (
  <Button uiType="load_more">
    <span>Button</span>
  </Button>
```

does. That makes me crazy

Any ideas?

Comment: According to your code, it contains a Button component, can you please share the related code about the Button component? I have created a sample which using your code to render the text (without using the Button component), it works well, so I think perhaps the issue is related to the Button component. Please explain more detail about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error message:

> `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner}).`.

Could you please show your component (specifically what `text` is assigned to)?

It seems like you wrote `const text = Button` instead of `const text = 'Button'`. Since you are importing `Button`, you are not getting an error about the assignment but the value of `text` is ReactType object instead of string. Adding quotes around the text should fix the issue.

Comment: I'm definitely have `const text = 'Button'`.  Plus it works in Chrome in both cases

Comment: I faced the same issue and the answer didn't work for me